# Unity 2 and Enterprise library configuration tool

Tags: .net, unity-container

Can someone show me how to use Enterprise library configuration tool with Unity2

Whatever I did, when I open the Enterprise library configuration tool, I could not have it working with a Unity config file.

When I click on the menu to add a new block, there is no Unity configuration block

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity 2.0 and documentation is available as a separate download as of today.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/unity

http://blogs.msdn.com/agile/archive/2010/04/20/microsoft-enterprise-library-5-0-released.aspx

Unfortunately the limited support for the Unity configuration in the Configuration Tool that you may have seen in one of the EntLib 5.0 betas didn't make it into the final release due to time constraints.

However, we have made the Unity configuration XML significantly easier to author with things like assembly and namespace aliasing to save having to repeatedly specify fully qualified types.

Answer (score 1):

We have released Unity 2.0 standalone, Unity 2.0 for Silverlight as well as Enterprise Library 5.0 full documentation set today.

Answer (score 0):

Unity 2 is not yet finalized (still in Beta 2). I guess we have to wait.

Besides, Unity 2 config file is much easier to be typed manually, compared to the 1.x versions.

Comment: Unity 2 has RTMed with Enterprise Library 5.
It is not in beta any more
The documentation is however still missing.

Comment: EntLib 5 does ship a newer version of Unity 2 (2.0.414), but I am not sure if that's the RTM build for Unity 2. Nowhere it was mentioned, even on http://unity.codeplex.com

Comment: The point is how to use Enterprise library configuration tool with Unity2

Comment: I am not from Unity team, but this page has ambiguity on the configuration tool, http://unity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Unity2Beta1ReleaseNotes&referringTitle=Unity2%20Beta1. Not sure if it means the Unity configuration tool will be included in Unity 2 final release. It does mention the configuration tool is in EntLib 5 beta 1, but I also find nothing regarding Unity 2 in EntLib 5 final. You may ask here, http://entlib.codeplex.com/Thread/List.aspx

Comment: actually, I saw it used here
http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/net/A-First-Look-at-Unity-2-0.aspx

Comment: If you read that article carefully, it states the tool in use is a beta. Probably it was the one in EntLib 5 beta 1.

Answer (score 0):

If interested in Unity config tool, which was part of the beta but didn't make it to the final EntLib5.0 release, you can find it [here](http://entlib.codeplex.com/releases/view/40138)